# use "between" with select for "dates"

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, between

What I'm exactly trying to do is something like :

Enter Date 1 and Date 2. 
The Date 1 and Date 2 can be like a full date format (YYYY-MM-DD) or just the year (YYYY) or even like this YYYY-MM

So I tried this for just one date (whatever the format, it works perfectly) :

`SELECT * FROM produit WHERE date_commande like "%'.$filtre_Date1.'%`

And now i wanna try with 2 dates :

`SELECT * FROM produit WHERE date_commande BETWEEN 
(SELECT date_commande  FROM produit WHERE date_commande like "%'.$filtre_Date1.'%) AND (SELECT date_commande   FROM produit WHERE date_commande like "%'.$filtre_Date2.'%)`

Where there is "2014-01" in "$filtre_Date1" and "2014-03" in "$filtre_Date2"

My problem :

My 2 sub-Select return more than 1 row.

Soo I guess there must be an another way to do put a kinda "like" in the 2 "between parameters" ?

Thanks.

Comment: You would be better served tagging this as a [tag:sql] question or [tag:mysql] or whatever database engine you're using. This really doesn't have anything to do with [tag:php].

Comment: Not only does your sub-query return more than one row, it most likely returns more than one column so that will never be valid input for your `BETWEEN` section. You are probably better off formatting your data correctly in php and feeding that directly to the `BETWEEN ... AND ...`. Depending on what the type of column for `date_commande` is...

Comment: i edited my 2 "sub-query"

Comment: So add a `LIMIT 1` to both as well. Your results will not be very reliable though...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(SELECT date_commande FROM produit WHERE date_commande like "%'.$filtre_Date2.'%)` ?

Comment: yes i edited but its not possible with the 2 sub-query i think :/ I post that just to get the idea what i am trying to do.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` in the comparisons?  What is the benefit to you of doing so?  Is the leading `%` relevant, even if the trailing one deals with the time component of the values?  And if the purpose of the trailing `%` is to deal with the time component, surely there's a better way using one of the time-related functions to get just the date.  Then you can simply use `BETWEEN` as in normal SQL.  What you've written is not 'normal' IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the logic you are looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM produit
WHERE date_format(date_commande, '%Y-%m-%d) BETWEEN $filtre_Date1 AND $filtre_Date2;
```

It sounds like the comparisons you want to do work correctly on the string form of the date, where the date is in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Booba__2012 . . . Oops, got that backwards somehow.  The function is `date_format()`.

Comment: ok I tried your version with =>  SELECT * FROM produit WHERE Date_Format(date_commande,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN "2014-01%" AND "2014-02%"  but it still shows me only the date from 2014-01 not from 2014-02 :/ I did something wrong ?

Comment: @Booba__2012 You can't use the wildcard `%` in a `BETWEEN` statement it will read it as a literal `%` character

Comment: ok, how would you do then to get the product from date 2014-01-19 to 2014-02 ?

Comment: @Booba__2012 . . . The above logic should work for your example.  It will select everything in January from the 19th onward plus all of February.

Comment: Ok thanks, I "kinda" resolve my problem. The 2 dates entered must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD and not like only YYYY-MM or YYYY.